# lexicographical create largest and smallest substring

Tags: java, string

problem statement:

Given a string,s, and an integer,k, complete the function so that it finds the lexicographically smallest and largest substrings of length k.

code :

```
public class Solution {

    public static String getSmallestAndLargest(String s, int k) {
        String substring = s.substring(0, k);
        String smallest = substring;
        String largest = substring;

        for (int i = 1; i <= s.length() - k; i++) { //This line
            // Create a substring of length 'k'
            substring = s.substring(i, i + k);

            // If current substring is lexicographically smaller than 'smallest'
            if (substring.compareTo(smallest) < 0) {
                smallest = substring;
            }

            // If current substring is lexicographically larger than 'largest'
            if (substring.compareTo(largest) > 0) {
                largest = substring;
            }
        }

        return smallest + "\n" + largest;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = scan.next();
        int k = scan.nextInt();
        scan.close();

        System.out.println(getSmallestAndLargest(s, k));
    }
}
```

I cannot understand mechanism of the marked line in the code. can anybody explain it to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you are talking about the following:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= s.length() - k; i++) { //This line
```

If `k` is the desired length then you need to make certain you don't iterate beyond the strings `effective length` to allow all substrings of length `k`.  Subtracting `k` simply adjusts the termination point to achieve that goal.

Here is an example.

`k = 5 and string length is 13.`

The goal is to iterate to `8` so that from `9 thru 13` remains a string of length `5`.  If we continued beyond that, the strings would be less than 5 and an error might occur.

Try the following:

```
       String str = "abcdefghij";
       int k = 4;

       for (int i = 0; i <= str.length() - k; i++) {
           System.out.println(str.substring(i,i+k));
       }
```

Notice the last substring is `ghij` which is the desired outcome.

Answer (score 1):

The for loop has `s.length() - k` in it because we are creating a new substring every time the loop iterates. We don't want the end of the substring to be out of the bounds of the string passed in, so we make sure the beginning of the substring won't go past `s.length() - k`.